# How do you hide the python dictionary hash number in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

The numbers next to `dict` keys (*hash numbers*) are not useful to me and sometimes push useful information off the screen. Is there way to hide them or not display them at all ?

[image: PyCharm hash numbers example]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand there is no way to currently hide it, but you can always open an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com.